# Table which increases row size when text is too big

Tags: tables, pdftex

I have a simple table:

```
    \begin{table}[]

        \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \cline{2-7} & 
            \multicolumn{1}{p{2.7cm}|}{RIGHT} & 
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{LEFT}&   
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{LEFT}&  
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{LEFT}&
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{LEFT}& 
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{LEFT} \\ \hline

            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{test1} & 1 & 1 &1 & 1 & 1 &1\\ \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{test2} & 1 & 1 &1 & 1 & 1 &1\\ \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{test2} & 1 & 1 &1 & 1 & 1 &1\\ \hline
        \end{tabular}

\end{table}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to make this table to fit in the page and to increase the row size when text is too long but I didn't manage to do that.

In the above table if in a cell I insert a long text it will look like this:
[image]

Someone help me to resize my table with this:

```
\newcommand*{\ResizeTableIfTooBig}[1]{%
%% #1 = table
\savebox{\MyTable}{#1}%
\ifdim\wd\MyTable<\linewidth
\usebox{\MyTable}%
\else
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\usebox{\MyTable}}%
\fi
}%
```

The problem is that this snapshot just scales the table and when text from cells is too long the font is very small.

What will help me is a table with 7 columns which will not come out of the paper and will create a new line when the text is too long for each column(without scaling font).
Something like this:
[image]

Comment: Don't use `\resizebox` on tables.

Comment: Then how can I fix this?

Comment: @samcarter sorry. I forgot about this. Done :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use  `tabularx` to make your table fit line width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx, lipsum}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]
\begin{table}[!htb]
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|>{\centering}p{2.7cm}|*{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}}
        \cline{2-7}
      \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & RIGHT & LEFT & LEFT & LEFT & LEFT & LEFT \\ 
       \hline
       test1 & 1 & 1 &1 & 1 & 1 & I vel II vel III vel \&c. \\ \hline
       test2 & 1 & 1 &1 & 1 & 1 &1 \\ \hline
       test2 & 1 & 1 &1 & 1 & 1 &1 \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Would that work?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

        \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \cline{2-7} &
            \multicolumn{1}{p{2.7cm}|}{RIGHT} &
            \multicolumn{1}{ >{\raggedright}p{2.5cm}<{} | }{LEFT LEFT LEFT LEFT LEFT LEFT LEFT LEFT }&
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{LEFT}&
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{LEFT}&
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{LEFT}&
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{LEFT} \\ \hline

            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{test1} & 1 & 1 &1 & 1 & 1 &1\\ \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{test2} & 1 & 1 &1 & 1 & 1 &1\\ \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{test2} & 1 & 1 &1 & 1 & 1 &1\\ \hline
        \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit:
It looks like you want the same behaviour in each cell of the table, and not only in some header cells, as I first thought. In this case, the following is probably more convenient:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}<{}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{C|C|C|C|C|C|C}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\ \hline
1 & 2 & LEFT LEFT LEFT LEFT LEFT LEFT LEFT LEFT & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 test test test tes tt test  \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It looks nice but if I add in the last right cell some more text it goes out of the page. (https://imgur.com/a/lzYGLgy)

Comment: of course it does. You need to use the `>{\raggedright}p{2.5cm}<{} |` style for each column you want to enter things.

Comment: here is what I have changed: https://pastebin.com/anvbMq1h . I am doing something wrong because the cell increases his size and goes out of the page.